# What if i set the model upon the success of model.save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am doing the following

```
var model = new Backbone.Model; // some new model
```

inside collection :

```
this.bind("change", this.onChange);
...... //
onChange: function( model, options ) {
    model.save(null, { 
       error : function() {
          console.log('error');
       },
       success: function() {
          model.set( someNewData );
          console.log('done');
       }
   });
},
```

In this case the browser sends two requests for updating the data.
First one for `model.save()` and second for `model.set()`.

Why is this so? In general when i do model.set() it will NOT send the request to server.. But when i do the same inside the success callback in side model.save(), then model.set() also sends the request.

Why this is so?
and how to avoid it?

Comment: With what you're showing, there's only one request http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/eekdb/

Comment: you are right. I found that i am calling model.save inside the 'change' event handler. So when i am setting model inside the success of model.save.. then again change event is called and again the model.save is called. Thats why i am getting twice requests.

Comment: Can u please help me to get rid off it. I do not want to send twice requests but surely i want to again set model inside success. And do mind that model.save resides inside the change event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the `change` event being triggered, you can pass a `silent: true` option to the `set` method:

```
model.set(someNewData, {silent: true});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/eekdb/6/

If you want the event but still want to cancel the save, you could pass a custom option to the `set` method. For example, a `fromsuccess` attribute:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('change', this.onChange);
    },

    onChange: function (model, options) {        
        if (options && options.fromsuccess)
            return;

        model.save(null, {
            success: function () {
                model.set({
                    data: 'data'
                }, {fromsuccess: true});
            }
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/eekdb/7/

Comment: I am agree with your answer but just want few clarifications..
check out now... and tell me please why there is two requests,,.... http://jsfiddle.net/eekdb/10/

Comment: Because `model.save({x:'Y'})` is equivalent to `model.set({x:'Y'}); model.save(null);` so your first `model.set` triggers a second `model.set`

Comment: please suggest how to avoid one of the two requests.. actually i want only one request and scalable.. The situation in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eekdb/10/ is exactly same as per my requirement... and please note that the order of two requests are quite unpredictable.. you run the same fiddle again.. you will see changes in its order.. So undesired.. why ? and how to resolve it?

Comment: That's what my answer does, pass `silent: true` or a custom flag to `model.set` and/or `model.save`